# How do I tag a specific build for sorting/filtering in Unity Performance Reporting?

Tags: unity, analytics

I am working in a Unity project where there are multiple versions of the app being build from the same code base.  The app being built is determined by a Script Define.  I want to be able to sort Unity Performance Reports based on the app I am building.  The app version can be the same across multiple apps in my case.

Unity Performance Reporting has filters, such as app version, but I cannot figure out how to add a custom filter.  I want to tag a build with the app being made, and then filter by that tag.

I have "Manager" access to the Dashboard.

Adding a custom tag during compile-time, run-time, or in the configuration settings is fine.  I just cannot figure out how. 
 This [Official Post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/new-performance-reporting-dashboard.523297/) does not have the information I am looking for.

How can I apply custom filters in Unity Performance Reporting?